# In jQuery QUnit how to get the assertion result from "equal()" assertion?

Tags: jquery, qunit

I have some functions that work with `Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);`, then to test them with the rest of the logic I use a `for` like:

```
test("getRandomNumber(anyNumber) should return a number between 1..anyNumber", function () {
    var anyNumber, result;

    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        anyNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
        result = getRandomNumber(anyNumber);

        equal((0 < result && result < (anyNumber + 1)), true);
     }
});
```

I want to get the result from `equal` assertion and if one assertion fails, doesn't need to stay in the loop, like:

```
test("getRandomNumber(anyNumber) should return a number between 1..anyNumber", function () {
    var anyNumber, result;

    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        anyNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
        result = getRandomNumber(anyNumber);

        if (!equal((0 < result && result < (anyNumber + 1)), true));
            break;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign it to a variable and check that.

```
var result = 0 < result && result < anyNumber + 1;

equal(result, true);

if ( ! result) {
    break;
}
```